# How to store the values in web server from i phone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, webserver

I am developing view based application.In my view i have register page in that page i have 
some fields like Firstname, lastname,e mail ID. When we click save button after entering the values these all field should be store in in webserver.In webserver i have application that application was developed using .net MVC Architecture and database is MYSQL .How i can store these values in webserver.

thanks for your response i have written this code is it right way to store values in webserver

```
 -(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender
{
    NSString* firstname = nameInput.text;
    NSString* lastname = passInput.text;
    NSString* bname = lastInput.text;
    NSString *post = 
    [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"fname=%@&lname=%@&email=%@",firstname,lastname,bname];

    NSData * postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];

    NSString * postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.yoursite.com/file.php?%@",post]]]; 
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSURLConnection * conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (conn) NSLog(@"Connection Successful");

}
@end
```

Comment: Provide some code , what u have done... then only u will get good response...

Comment: I have sent code in above is it right way?

Comment: see u r getting responses... as soon as u provide some code or something useful.. others feel free to help u.And whenever u feel some answer is good Upvote him or tick the answer when that solves ur problem, both these things increases ur repo in SO which inturn helps u in getting more suggestions or answers for ur problems... :) Good Day

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) Develop a proper API that your iOS app can call using libraries like ASIHTTPRequest or AFNetworking

2) Have a .NET form processor in place, just like you would to process an HTML form, and then use ASIHTTPRequest, AFNetworking, or something similar to submit the request to this processor using the POST method and with the parameters you would like to store added to the request. This simulates an HTML form that has been filled and submitted, and then you can do whatever you wish with the data .NET receives. Both ASI and AFNetworking have pretty extensive documentation on how these types of requests are implemented on iOS with their respective libraries. Unfortunately, ASI is no longer being maintained, so I would recommend going with AFNetworking if possible.

### RESPONSE TO UPDATE:

I only gave it a quick look over, but everything looks good to me. The only thing I would change is this: 
     [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.yoursite.com/file.php?%@",post]]]; 

 to this: 

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.yoursite.com/file.php"]]];

What you will need now is code on the web side in that file.php that can process the request. It would use the typical $_POST['var_name_here'] to grab the data that is passed to it.

Comment: This is correct for the app, but now you will need the PHP file (or any other language like .NET) that can process the request. In PHP, you would be using the $_POST array

Comment: You are saying now you will need the PHP file (or any other language like .NET) i am not gettind could you explain some more clear

Comment: What I am saying is that iOS cannot directly save to the web server. It is not a web server language like .NET and PHP are. You mentioned to another user that this was originally a web app made in .NET. So for the iPhone app to communicate with the server, it would need access to this .NET app in order to post this request to it. This is just like posting an HTML form to a .NET page that holds a method to process the form and save the data, except the form is the iPhone app and not an HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a webapplication in your preferred language and deploy it to some webserver or hosting service. To get started, you should choose a language PHP, Java, Python, C# or whatever and google how you could implement a webservice within that language.

I would do this in Java and implement a [RESTful wbeservice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) that sends and receives [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML).

Comment: Actually application was implemented in using .Net MVC architecture and hosted in server. Now i am implementing for iPhone.